# Draw this planar graph

Tags: visual, graph-theory

The playing board for this puzzle is a short list of digits; there is one rule governing possible moves: The `1` may swap with a digit one place to the right; the `2` may swap with a digit two places to the right, and so on.

For example, in the list `1,3,7,2,6,5,4`, you can swap `3` and `6`, because the latter is 3 places to the right of `3`:

```
┌─┐
┷ ▼
1,3,7,2,6,5,4     →     3,1,7,2,6,5,4
```

The only other legal moves from this position are to swap `1` and `3` (yielding `3,1,7,2,6,5,4`) or to swap `2` and `5` (yielding `1,6,7,5,3,2,4`):

```
  ┌─────┐
  ┷     ▼
1,3,7,2,6,5,4     →     1,6,7,2,3,5,4

      ┌───┐
      ┷   ▼
1,3,7,2,6,5,4     →     1,3,7,5,6,2,4
```

Here is a graph of all possible states reachable from `1,2,3`:

```
123 → 213 → 312 → 321
       ↓     ↑
      231 → 132
```

(For lists of few digits, let's just omit the separating commas).

**For the 24 states reachable from `1,2,3,4`, the corresponding graph can be drawn. Do so, and make sure to avoid crossing lines!**

Bonus points for symmetries, aesthetics, and for using ASCII-art (or Unicode text `─` `│` `┌` `┐` `└` `┘`).

<sub>If you need to omit the arrowheads, or the labels that distinguish the nodes, that's okay as long as the nodes are recognizable. Maybe mark the `1234` and `4321` nodes.</sub>

Is there a cycle (some sequence of two or more moves, after which the board state is the same in the beginning) for any permutation of the numbers `1,2,...,n`, any `n`?

Comment: I think your second example should be 1372654 -> 1375624?

Comment:  I have no proof that this graph is cycle-free, so I've [asked on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3691755/792692).—Someone is pondering a [codegolf question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18965/95359) based on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fact that flipping all sequences flips all the arrows makes for some very nice graph symmetries:

> [image]

Anyone with way too much time on their hands is free to play with the length-5 version [here](http://graphonline.ru/en/?graph=TmheqLaFdXYTTUoj).

Comment: I'd be surprised if the length-5 version could be drawn without crossing lines, though!

Comment: Of course, but maybe it has lower crossing number than it appears...

Answer (score 7):

ASCII art rendering of completed graph:

> ```
>  .------------------------------------.
>  |                                    |
>  |    .---------->4321<-----------.   |
>  |    |                           |   |
>  |    |                           |   |
>  |  4312<--4132<--1432<--1234   2341  |
>  |    ^      ^             |      ^   |
>  |    |      |             v      |   |
>  '->4213-->4231          2134-->2314  |
>       ^                    |      |   |
>       |                    v      v   |
>  .->4123<----------------3124<--1324  |
>  |    ^                    |          |
>  |    |                    v          |
>  |  1423<--3421<--3412<--3214---------'
>  |    ^      ^      ^      |
>  |    |      |      |      v
>  |  2413-->2431     |    3241-->1243--.
>  |    ^             |      |      |   |
>  |    |             |      |      v   |
>  '--2143<---------3142<----'    1342  |
>       ^             |             |   |
>       |             '-------------'   |
>       |                               |
>       '-------------------------------'
> ```

Comment: Beautiful layout!
One survey respondent says:
"yes please for vertical `|` stems on up/down arrow heads."
It would make their directions quicker to see.  
By the way, `.` periods and `\` '` apostrophes can work well at corners
(where `\\ /`slashes are at present).
 ASCII-affectionately

Answer (score 4):

I think this works, without crossing lines:

> [image: planar graph v3]

I’d imagine the answer to the second question is

> No. Consider a string of length n, with elements i=1,...,n and positions j=1,...,n. Once element n is moved away from position n, it can never return to its initial position. This is because moving from position j, j != n, to position n requires an element of at most n-1. So we conclude that element i=n must stay in place in order for this sequence to work. This is then equivalent to creating a cycle from a string of length n-1, with elements i=1,...,n-1 and positions j=1,...,n-1. We see that, by similar logic to the above, element i=n-1 must also stay in place (moving from position j, j != n-1, to position n-1 requires an element of at most n-2). By induction it follows that the starting position can not be arrived at after any moves have been made.

Comment: You are missing 2341

Comment: Shoot, it was in my original diagram and forgot to transcribe — thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

> Explore paths from `3124` to `4213` first.

Here's my own answer using unicode line-drawing characters (without arrowheads) - different lines for swaps depending on their offset:

> ```
>       ┌─────────────────────────────────────────2341
>      2314═══1324                                  ║
>       │      │                                    ║
>      2134═══3124───────────────────────┐          ║
>       │      ┃   ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━3241───3214━━┓      ║
>       │      ┃   ┃              ║      ║   ┃   ▃▃▃║▃▃
>       │      ┃  1243═══1342───3142───3412  ┃   ▉4321▉
>       │      ┃   │┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛     ┃│   ┃   ▀▀▀│▀▀
>     ▃▃│▃▃▃   ┃   │┃     ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛│   ┃      │
>     ▉1234▉   ┃  2143───2413───2431═══3421  ┃      │
>     ▀▀║▀▀▀   ┃   ║      ║              ┃   ┃      │
>       ║      ┗━━4123───1423━━━━━━━━━━━━┛   ┃      │
>       ║          └───────────────────────4213═══4312
>       ║                                    │      │
>       ║                                  4231═══4132
>      1432 ────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

Unicode within `<pre>` within a spoiler was a puzzle of its own. Kudos to Daniel!

Comment: Wait, why does 3412 connect to 4213 directly? Doesn’t it need to connect 3412 > 3214 > 4213?

Comment: El-Guest, you're right! Corrected.

Comment: Thank you! Also, why does 3412 not connect to 2413?